# singular event with singular verb

Tags: grammar, verbs

Is the use of the contracted negative form of Do, the DON'T, in reference to a singular event or action acceptable in formal writings as is in song lyrics composition?

Comment: Wrong about finding it funny? Humour is subjective.

Comment: Song lyrics are a text used for a performance. One can't assume a grammatical error isn't an intentional piece of the art.

Comment: *It don't make sense* is idiomatic dialogue, ungrammatical, but certainly not objectionable in song lyrics, *especially* in Country & Western songs.

Comment: Once again, I remark on the strangeness of a question from someone who knows very little about grammar, questioning the correctness of a published text composed by a native speaker. And the equal strangeness of an answer from someone who knows about the same amount of grammar, confirming the questioner's odd presuppositions. I remark on this only because no one else thinks it's odd. Here, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

No, he was not wrong in any grammatical way.
Note that these are song lyrics, with special rules.
These rules have to do with meter and rhyme, and in print with capitalization.
Punctuation is pretty optional, and the dialect may vary from Standard English, as songs often do.

> *It's funny how a greater plan Is too hard to understand Right now it don't make sense.*

Four clauses, with **[Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299)**, [***Tough*-Movement**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/143566/15299), and **[Indefinite Subject Deletion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73687/15299)**,
in 2 sentences

- *[It's funny [how a greater plan is too hard [to understand]]].*
- *[Right now it don't make sense].*

I won't go into the parse of the first sentence.
Both sentences are in colloquial American rural English,
a sociolect with some characteristic regularizations of auxiliary verbs.

Many irregular auxiliary verb constructions get regularized, like *ain't* as a contraction of *am not*.
One such is that the 3SgPres negative contraction of [***Do*-Support**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299) *do* becomes *don't*,
instead of the irregular *doesn't*.

Is that what you were worried about?

Comment: +1 for making me smile. A lovely, accurate, and deliciously overstated answer. I understand your concern, and I think your answer serves well to underline it :) .

Comment: Who breaks a buttefly upon a wheel?

Comment: Is this gonna be on the final?

Answer (score 0):

Depends. If you understand what he's trying to say, then no he isn't wrong. If you don't understand, then yes. 
Poets and lyricists often bend grammatical rules to express their thoughts. And as long as we enjoy the lyrics and the song, who cares?