# What is "it" in the following sentence: It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts

Tags: syntactic-analysis, antecedents, dummy-it

I am very confused. Unless I am mistaken, I know "it" has to be a noun of some sort, but I am unable to figure out what noun "it" is referring to.

What is "it" in the following sentence:

> It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts.

Heres another couple of examples:

> It is impossible to fly.

Comment: Related: [“It is fun to write letters” vs. “It is fun writing letters”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73686/it-is-fun-to-write-letters-vs-it-is-fun-writing-letters/73687#73687)

Comment: I understand how this relates but it unfortunately does not help with this question.

Comment: I see. Can you clarify further what you mean by "what is it"? Are you asking about how to interpret the meaning of "it" in this sentence, or about what it is called in terms of syntax?

Comment: “It” is the fact that Bob likes doughnuts. That fact is clear.

Comment: Just Updated. Thanks! But what about the second example?

Comment: @Josh -- Second example?  "It" is the name of my pet turtle.

Comment: Weather that was sarcastic or not it is incorrect. If your pet turtle's name is "Harry" then you should be able to replace "it" with "Harry" then the sentence would read "Harry is impossible to fly" which does not make sense. The correct sentence should be "It is impossible for Harry to fly" Which brings us back to what is "it"? Therefore your answer is incorrect. But thanks!

Comment: In the second example, “it” is [a dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun?wprov=sfti1), used because the syntax of English requires it, but the semantics of the utterance doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks! If you add your answer as an answer instead of a comment Ill mark it solved otherwise I can just add it myself. For anyone looking here is a good article that explains dummy pronouns extensively: http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/

Comment: The first sentence is an 'it-cleft' sentence and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) has a fair amount to say about the 'it' pronoun in the intro and under the 'Structural issues' heading.

Comment: @Dan Bron Clearly, there are different analyses.

Comment: @Josh - What if I climb on the back of my turtle and expect him to fly?

Comment: Yes, 'It' is a dummy subject.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *it* in both example sentences is, as noted, a "dummy *it*" -- that is, this *it* is not referential,
and thus doesn't have any meaning, because meaning in pronouns is a matter of reference only.

**This** dummy *it* (there are [several others](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95947/15299)) is an artifact of a syntactic rule called [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/119893/15299), which works to make sure that "heavy" subject noun phrases (clauses and the like) don't show up
at the beginning of the sentence where they're hard to process, like this  unwieldy example:

- ***For a child to open this package** is difficult.*

Instead, Extraposition inserts a dummy *it* in place of the heavy NP and shifts it to the end,
where it is much easier to process.

- ***It** is difficult **for a child to open this package**.*

Of course, Extraposition is governed by the matrix predicate (in this case *be difficult*), and some predicates require it, others forbid it, and many allow it under certain circumstances. Like all syntactic rules; nothing new here.

As the the original question -- what is *it*?
The answer is that it's several things:

1. it's a neuter personal pronoun
2. it's a dummy pronoun (i.e, it's a pronoun with no reference)
3. it's the subject of the sentence (and therefore a noun phrase, though one without reference)

Comment: What’s an example of a predicate that forbids extraposition?

Comment: Oh, for instance, _seem_ and _appear_ only allow Extraposition with _that_ complements (_It seems/appears that he's late_), but they require A-Raising with infinitive complements (_He seems/appears to be late_ but not *_It seems/appears for him to be late_).

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it feels like this device may have evolved as a way to "un-Germanify" sentences, if you know what I mean: to avoid that characteristic of German wherein you don't know what the sentence is about till you get to the end.

Comment: The verb goes at the end only in tensed subordinate clauses in German. Infinitive clauses work much the same way as in English.

Answer (score 1):

In both sentences, *It* fills in for the subject of the sentence.

In the example "It is impossible to fly," *It* is substituted for the subject  "to fly".

- To fly is impossible.

In the sentence "It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts", *It* anticipates the subject (this time a *that* clause) "That Bob likes doughnuts".

- That Bob likes doughnuts is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from the comments:

In the first example "it" refers to "the fact that Bob likes doughnuts."

In the second example "it" is a dummy pronoun and therefore does not refer to anything.

Links for more information on Dummy Pronouns:

- [Wikipedia: Dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun?wprov=sfti1)
- [Bright Hub Education: English Grammar Pronouns: Existential There and Dummy It](http://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/)

Comment: Not everyone thinks *it* is referential in cleft sentences. You should provide some support for that point of view for this particular sentence.