# Should "it/this" always refer to a specific noun?

Tags: grammaticality, antecedents, grammatical-roles, dummy-it

I have a paragraph starting with the below sentence. "it" is not referring to any specific noun. Is there any problem with that?

> ***It***  has been estimated that health care costs accounted for 11.6% of Canada’s GDP in 2019, the majority of which were spent in hospitals.

Best, Amir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "it" in the following sentence: It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419319/what-is-it-in-the-following-sentence-it-is-clear-that-bob-likes-doughnuts) This is the _dummy 'it'_ associated with extraposition. In John Lawler's answer to the duplicate question, he gives a link to an article stating that there are various _dummy it_'s (non-referential) as well as the usual referential version. The French conveniently use a different word ('ce' rather than 'il' etc).

Comment: This is one example where the non-extraposed equivalent would not be possible.