# That-clause in "it seems that"

Tags: complements

Is the that-clause in the following sentence a predicative complement or a displaced subject with *it* being the dummy subject?

> It seemed that he was correct.

My understanding is that if the that-clause is a subject, then the sentence could be paraphrased to *That he was correct seemed.* which seems ungrammatical.

It would become grammatical though, if *to be true* is added.

> That he was correct seemed (to be true).

I don't know whether I can analyze a sentence like that.

However, if the *that-clause* is a predicative complement, then what does *it* refer to?

Comment: See [The Cliffs on Equi and Raising](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), referenced by Lawler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "it" in the following sentence: It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419319/what-is-it-in-the-following-sentence-it-is-clear-that-bob-likes-doughnuts)

Comment: I learned a new term: [***IT-Extraposition***.](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~kay/bcg/extrap.html) Apparently we used to be able to say ***Meseems this is correct***, where we now have to say ***It seems [to me] [that] this is correct***.

Comment: Extraposition is irrelevant here, since the OP's example is not an extraposition construction.

Comment: The example "It is clear that Bob likes doughnuts" is irrelevant since **unlilke the OP's example** it is an extraposition construction.

Answer (score 1):

> *It seemed* [*that he was correct*].

The subject "it" is semantically empty here, so it's not possible for the bracketed declarative content clause to function as PC, though it is an internal complement of "seemed".

The construction bears some resemblance to an extraposition construction, but differs in that the subordinate clause cannot occupy subject position: "*That he was correct seemed" is of course totally ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

You would never have a that-clause if "it" was not a dummy subject. ([OALD, 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/seem?q=seem))

> it seems | it would seem
> used to suggest that something is true when you are not certain or when you want to be polite
> seem (that)… It would seem that we all agree.
> This last point, it seems to me, is particularly important.
> adj. It seems only reasonable to ask students to buy a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys.
While I was learning the new classification of finite clauses proposed in CGEL, I came across [a paper by Huddleston and Pullum](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/FiniteSubordinateClauses.pdf) , on which a footnote says

> 6 In the construction with seem, which Seppänen & Herriman (2002) argue persuasively does not involve extraposition, the subordinate clause cannot occur in subject position: It seems that she’s right, but not *That she’s right seems. Here, then, there is no possibility of having a noun in place of the noun clause (without a change in the interpretation of it, i.e. a change of construction).

I have yet to read the work by Seppänen & Herriman but I believe I am not far from the answer. And I can see clearly my confusion arose because I mixed up the so-called nominal clause with a noun.

Comment: Please drop the term 'noun clause'. You know why!